# How to fit a nested glm model using deviance for selectio?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, deviance, nested-models

I have weight as response variable which is continuous variable. And 3 explanatory variables viz; Parity(Count), Age(continuous) and Sex(Factor).
I want to fit a glm model using deviances analysis to select the best model from all possible plausible model.
The models are nested.
How do I go about it pls. Knowing that the assumptions are met since Normality is not neccessary.
Pls help me.

Comment: Do you mean determining which combination of the three variables results in the best model? If so, best in what sense? // Why is normality not necessary? Deviance involves a likelihood. Do you have one in mind if it isn’t Gaussian?

Comment: Like Model1=Weight~Age+Sex+parity+interactions as my full model.

Comment: And other possible models from the nest. Then use deviance analysis to compare the models and select the best. Thank you

Comment: Yes Guassian as the link

Comment: Please edit your Q to include extra information in comments. Comments on this site are ephemeral and often only seen by a few

Comment: Can I share the whole data, and a summary of the methodology pls. Its like I find it a little hard to use this site. Not a fan of social media that much. I can share it on whats app if possible pls. +2347034345323 thanks